# XML Design - Performance and Efficiency

Tags: php, xml, performance, loops, coding-efficiency

I am making an XML map file for categories. I was wondering what the right approach would be considering the two options i have in mind.

My main issue is speed/efficiency of the php code that may have to read the XML file.
So here is my first approach

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<category-map lang="en_US" reader="Candor Framework">

    <for-her url="/content/syl/tags/for-her">

        <women-tops url="/content/syl/category/15/women-tops">
            <women-longsleeve-tops url="/content/syl/tags/women-longsleeve-tops">Longsleeve Tops</women-longsleeve-tops>
            <women-shortsleeve-tops url="/content/syl/tags/women-shortsleeve-tops">Shortsleeve Tops</women-shortsleeve-tops>
        </women-tops>
        <women-gowns url="/content/syl/category/18/women-gowns/">
            <short-gowns url="/content/syl/tags/short-gowns">Short Gowns</short-gowns>
            <evening-gowns url="/content/syl/tags/evening-gowns">Evening Gowns</evening-gowns>
        </women-gowns>
        <women-shoes url="/content/syl/category/19/women-shoes/">
            <women-highheel-shoes url="/content/syl/tags/women-highheel-shoes">High Heel Shoes</women-highheel-shoes>
            <women-wedge-shoes url="/content/syl/tags/women-wedge-shoes">Wedge Shoes</women-wedge-shoes>
        </women-shoes>
    </for-her>

    <for-him url="/content/syl/tags/for-him">
        <men-shirt url="/content/syl/category/20/men-shirt">
          <men-lonsleeve-shirt url="/content/syl/tags/men-longsleeve-shirt">Longsleeve Shirt</women-longsleeve-tops>
        </men-shirt>
    </for-him>

</category-map>
```

with this approach, all XML tags have unique names. Now compare with this second approach.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<category-map lang="en_US" reader="Candor Framework">

    <target name="for-her" url="/content/syl/tags/for-her">

        <category name="women-tops" url="/content/syl/category/15/women-tops">
            <tag name="women-longsleeve-tops" url="/content/syl/tags/women-longsleeve-tops">Longsleeve Tops</tag>
            <tag name="women-shortsleeve-tops" url="/content/syl/tags/women-shortsleeve-tops">Shortsleeve Tops</tag>
        </category>
        <category name="women-gowns" url="/content/syl/category/18/women-gowns/">
            <tag name="short-gowns" url="/content/syl/tags/short-gowns">Short Gowns</tag>
            <tag name="evening-gowns" url="/content/syl/tags/evening-gowns">Evening Gowns</tag>
        </category>
        <category name="women-shoes" url="/content/syl/category/19/women-shoes/">
            <tag name="women-highheel-shoes" url="/content/syl/tags/women-highheel-shoes">High Heel Shoes</tag>
            <tag name="women-wedge-shoes" url="/content/syl/tags/women-wedge-shoes">Wedge Shoes</tag>
        </category>
    </target>

    <target name="for-him" url="/content/syl/tags/for-him">
        <category name="men-shirt" url="/content/syl/category/20/men-shirt">
          <tag name="men-lonsleeve-shirt" url="/content/syl/tags/men-longsleeve-shirt">Longsleeve Shirt</tag>
        </category>
    </target>

</category-map>
```

This is a short version of the XML file. The entire content is quite much. Which of these design approach is faster?, which one requires less loops and conditionals? which would one advise to follow and why?

Much Appreciated!

Comment: Try to define the format (write a text description or better an XSD). If it gets to complex, the format is wrong. :-) The second one is better, the first one is missing the semantic information what is a category/tag. Describing it would be a pain, and so will be using it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion I would say that the second one is best, purely because it is more general and thus extensible with no updates required.

I view XML as a mechanism for code to communicate with other blocks of code, so the structure should reflect what is best for the code and not necessarily have any structure that makes it easier for a human to read. To me the first XML looks like it was written for a human and not a computer, where as the second is more in tune with how a data base would store information: i.e. select rows where target == for-him and catagory == men-shirt.

In terms of performance, I would imagine they are equivalent as you might find you code both up the same, since the first XML is really using using element names instead of name attributes. This would especially be the case if your code it to be extensible ready for new elements to be added in your first case.

If you have a lot of data, consider storing it in a database instead like sqlite using a schema which reflects your second XML. You can then export to XML or JSON for any clients the results of queries.

Comment: It's odd how XML was designed to be extensible by allowing you to use an infinite number of different element names, but people somehow don't believe this: they try to use a small number of element names and a large number of attribute values because they think this is more extensible. I don't see the logic; except possibly when you are using tools such as data-binding that assume a fixed vocabulary of elements and attributes.

Comment: Well I would say you add elements when there is a clear need to identify different entities and hierarchy. Where you have something like a category of clothing, then you only need one element. It would not make sense to keeping adding elements for things like shoes, hand bags etc every time you add something new. From a life-cycle perspective, adding new elements means updating XML schemas, client/server code and anything dependent on the original schema. Better to go for a schema which is clear but can be flexible with minimal code changes between major releases IMHO.

Comment: Yes, in many domains there is a clear distinction between instances and types: the concepts of products and customers (types) are relatively stable, while the names of actual products and customers (instances) are fast-changing, and it usually makes sense for the element and attribute names to refer to types rather than instances (unlike JSON practice, by the way). But types and instances aren't always completely distinguishable, for example if you have types of product (men's, women's and children's clothing) then these subcategories could go either side of the type/instance divide.